# Inserting a component just like javascript's insertBefore function

Tags: angular

I want to insert a dynamically created component in these modes:

```
Starting case: 
<div id="X">
</div>
```

Insert a new component inside the div with a id of X, resulting to this..

```
<div id="X">
<new-component></new-component>
</div>
```

and then, after a button click/or any event (async etc...) I want to insert an new component before the first inserted component.

```
<div id="X">
<new-component></new-component> // the new component inserted 
<new-component></new-component> //the first inserted component
</div>
```

and vice versa, I want to insert a component after a given reference node again just like javascript's insert node.

What I'm thinking of is to get the component's element and adjusting it manually via js. Is there a better way to perform these functions without resulting to that? Thanks. I'm using angular 4 by the way.

Comment: The straightforward way is to use ngFor. Use ngFor trackBy to track particular components. Otherwise you will likely end up with ComponentFactoryResolver and Renderer.

Comment: @estus I tried just now reordering the array depending on my preference. It satisfies my problem. Just new to angular and I thought any manipulation in the array will not reflect during the ngFor's execution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you are looking to realise something like this:

**Parent HTML:**

```
<button type="button" (click)=add()>Add</button>
 <div *ngFor="let child of children; let i = index">
    <child [childId]="child.id.toString()"></child> 
 </div>
```

**Parent Class:**

```
  children = [];
  add() {
    //add at the start
    this.children.unshift({id:this.children.length+1});
  }
```

**Child HTML**

```
  <input type="text" [value]="'I am child number'+ childId">
```

**Child class:**

```
export class ChildComponent {
  // to keep the track of the child
  @Input('childId') private childId;
}
```

So you don't have to manipulate the DOM directly.

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UgDIY2YU1ksxG9pk2dMp?p=preview)